# function applied to dataset R

Tags: r, function, object, dataset

Below are two dataframes labeled as 'A' and 'C'. I have created a function that would take the top 5 rows for dataframe and want the same applied to dataframe C. However, it only replicates it for A. How would I have this function be applied for C only. Thanks!

```
    L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
    fac <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)
    (d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10, fac = fac))
    ## The "same" with automatic column names:
    A<-data.frame(1, 1:10, sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE))

    L3 <- LETTERS[7:9]
    fac <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)
    (d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10, fac = fac))
    ## The "same" with automatic column names:
    C<-data.frame(1, 1:10, sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE))

    function_y<-function(Data_Analysis_Task) {
       sample2<-head(A, 5)
       return(sample2)
    }

    D<-function_y(C)
```

Comment: head(Data_Analysis_Task, 5) || This should solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to have the same argument passed inside the function as well

```
function_y <- function(Data_Analysis_Task) {
      head(Data_Analysis_Task, 5)

 }

 D <- function_y(C)
```

---

If we use `head(A, 5)`, inside the function, it looks for the object 'A', inside the function env first, then if it doesn't find, looks at the parent env, and so on until it finds the object 'A' in the global env.  So, it would return the same output of `head` of 'A' every time the function is called